# How can I make this leveling system work?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make my leveling system. When someone *crosses* the line for xP required they should level up, the method should print this info as well as some operator functions. Only when value a, crosses value b. Or in this case. If value a is no longer value a, but changes to b. But only when it changes.

```
// Leveling system
    String[] levels = {"Bitch", "Trainee", "Rookie", "Supervisor", "Pro", "Killer Machine", "Infamous", "Legendary", "Badass", "Badass MOFO"};
    Integer[] xPs = {250, 750, 1500, 3000, 5000, 8000, 12000, 18000, 24000, 36000};
    Integer[] maxHealthArray = {155, 190, 225, 260, 295, 330, 365, 400, 435, 470};


 if(xP < xPs[0]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[0]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[0];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[1]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[1]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[1];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[2]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[2]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[2];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[3]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[3]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[3];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[4]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[4]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[4];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[5]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[5]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[5];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[6]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[6]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[6];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[7]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[7]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[7];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[8]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[8]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[8];
            }
            else if(xP < xPs[9]) {
                System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);
                System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + levels[9]);
                maxHealth += maxHealthArray[9];
```

Comment: Change the order of the if statements so that `(xP < xPs[9])` comes first and `(xP < xPs[0])` last. Also add an additional check to each statement `(xP >= xPs[8])  && (xP < xPs[9])`. This additional check might not be necessary depending on your requirements

Comment: Why not use a loop with a control variable going from 0 to 9 (or 9 to 0) so that you don't end up with ten copies of virtually the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set your levels in an enum?

```
public enum Levels {
    BITCH("bitch", 250, 155);
    TRAINEE("trainer", 750, 190);

    private final String level;
        private final int xP;
        private final int maxHealth;

    private Levels(String level, int xP, int maxHealth) {
            this.level = level;
            this.xP = xP;
            this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
        }

    public String getLevel(){
        return this.level;
    }

    public int getXP(){
        return this.xP;
    }

    public int getMaxHealth(){
        return this.maxHealth;
    }
}
```

and use EnumSet to loop through:

```
EnumSet.allOf(Levels.class).forEach(level -> {
   if (xP < level.getXP()){
      System.out.println("\nYour xP is: " + xP);   
      System.out.println("You have reached a rank of: " + level.getLevel());
      maxHealth += level.getMaxHealth();
     }
   }
);
```

Please note the above code is not really tested, but should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think what OP wants is something that triggers once-only at the XP boundary condition. If we continue the `Enum` idea:

```java
  enum Level {
    Paladin(750, 190, null),
    Peon(250, 155, Paladin);

    private final int maxXp;
    private final int healthBuff;
    private final Level next;

    Level(int maxXp, int healthBuff, Level next) {
      this.healthBuff = healthBuff;
      this.maxXp = maxXp;
      this.next = next; // Questionable means to know "next" Level but is at least final
    }

    // returns null if not applicable
    Level promotionLevel(int xp) {
      return xp > maxXp ? next : null;
    }
  }


  public void checkPromotion() {
    Level next;
    // while() handles multiple promotions, might not be relevant
    while ((next = this.level.promotionLevel(this.xp)) != null) {
      promoteTo(next); 
    }
  }
```